# Saving PHP Session variables to local variables

Tags: php, session-variables

Im having a big problem, i am generating content with my php script. I pass some `text-input` to my generating script. This script is putting all `text-input`to the `$_SESSION` variable.

For example :

```
$_SESSION[text1] = $text1;
$_SESSION[text2] = $text2;
```

and so on...

In the generated page i take those `$_SESSION` variables and put them to local variables.

For example :

```
$text1 = $_SESSION['text1']
$text2 = $_SESSION['text2']
```

and so on...

But after i destroy the session (Cause of login/logout system) all the content on the generated site is gone. Only the HTML tags are still there. So that means for me, all session variables get empty after destroying the session.

My question now is how do i save those session variables without loosing them after a    `session_destroy();`?

Ps: Im using a MySQL-Database but im not so talented with it.

Comment: What do you want to do with those variables? Ofcourse after you destroy your session and reload your page the variables will be empty.

Comment: I want to save them "forever" so i wont loose the content of the variables.

Comment: Then you will have to resort to some sort of database be it in the form of SQL, File or noSQL databases.

Comment: @Slint7789 Niek van der Maaden is right. The best options is to use a database. Just take some time to learn a bit more SQL. It's not very hard to understand and there's a lot of good tutorials about it. It's an everyday use for me, and generally, you always use a database with PHP, so it's worth the the learn :)

Comment: Then, why do you need to destroy session in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Session var are destroyed after session_destroy, it is how it works. You can save what you want in mysql DB, in a file (json format), mongodb, in memcached, in redis ...
You can also use cookies for simple and non secure var.
A very simple thing is to save it in a file :

```
file_puts_content('filename.json',json_encode($_SESSION));
```

and to get it back

```
$_SESSION=json_decode(file_gets_content('filename.json'),true);
```

But it's much better to do it with a database.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to store them in the MySQL Database. 
Use PDO connector to insert rows in your tables  : [[Doc Here]](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php)

And Insert like this :

```
INSERT INTO my_table(`var1`,`var2`,`var3`) VALUES($val1,$val2,$val3);
```

What is the context of the application ?